# After Ajax Refresh, Elements are not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

After the Ajax refresh of div tag with new data,

Here i try to get value of radio button [checked], by using the following code.

**Before HTML :**

```
<div id="summery">

</div>
```

**jQuery Block 1 :**

```
       $.ajax({
                url: site_addr + '/new_row_rec',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (res) {
                    /** If error is hit, then redirect */
                    if (res.error_url) {
                        location.reload(res.error_url);
                    }
                    $('#summery').html(res);
                }
            });
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="summery">
      <input type="radio" name="payment_type[]" class="payment_type"
                                               value="A">

      <input type="radio" name="payment_type[]" class="payment_type"
                                               value="B">
    </div>
```

**jQuery Block 2 :**

```
$('.payment_type').on('click', function () {
   var row = $('input[name="payment_type"]:checked').val();
   console.log('Row : ' + row)
 }
```

I get error as :

```
 Row : undefined
```

Here, **jQuery Block 1** is executed first and html contents are loaded.
After that, **jQuery Block 2** is run by on click event of radio button.

I think there is an element binding issue, is it so. Then what's the solution for this ?

or

Any other ways to get the value of radio button after the refresh.

Note : jQuery Event Trigger on Main Page to Newly Loaded Page.

Comment: Please complete the syntax of console.log('your contents') like this.

Comment: Try this with on or bind 

$(document).on('click', '.payment_type', function(){
//Here is your code
});

Comment: i fix syntax now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input`s' name is `payment_type[]` so the jQuery statements should have been:

```
$('.payment_type').on('click', function () {
   var row = $('input[name="payment_type[]"]:checked').val();
   console.log('Row : ' + row)
});
```

As a result:

[image]

Comment: but this doesn't solve his problem that after the ajax request the event listeners aren't working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `.payment_type` is added from the ajax try this

```
 $('body').on('click','.payment_type',function () {
   var row = $('input[name^="payment_type"]:checked').val();
   console.log('Row : ' + row)
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the **jQuery Block 2** like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.payment_type', function () {
   var row = $('input[name="payment_type[]"]:checked').val();
   console.log('Row : ' + row);
}
```

Your DOM changes due to your AJAX request, so previously bound event listeners aren't correct anymore. You have to bind the event listener to the document.

Comment: Ya, you are right. but this document level event listener generated as how many radio buttons i have.